# No mapping found error Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I made a very simple Spring MVC application to learn AOP, yet each time I try to navigate any of the application pages, I get (No mapping found) error as follows:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TestAOP/page1.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

I've doubled checked web.xml, servlet-context.xml, controller code but couldn't notice anything wrong. So I will appreciate it so much if someone can please look at the content of my web.xml, servlet-context.xml and controller and let me know what I am missing here and how I can overcome this error.  Thanks for your time

1. Web.xml

   ```
     <context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
     </context-param>

     <listener>
       <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
     </listener>

     <servlet>
       <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>              
     <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
   ```
2. servlet-context.xml

> ```
>   <annotation-driven />
>   <context:component-scan base-package="com.sampledomain.app.controller" />
>
>   <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
>
>   <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
>
>   <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
>     <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
>     <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
>   </beans:bean>
> ```

1. Controller

   ```
   @Controller
   public class HomeController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/page1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String firstPage(HttpServletRequest request,Locale locale, Model model) {        
       Date date = new Date();
       DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);   
       String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date); 
       model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );
       return "page01";
   }
   }
   ```
2. root-context.xml
   Is mainly empty

Note: page01.jsp is under /WEB-INF/views/ folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to double check whether the Controller is instantiated by spring. The easiest way is to create an empty constructor with a sysout("my controller has been instantiated!!!") or whatever and lets see whether this line is in the catalina.out. Take a look whether

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sampledomain.app.controller" />
```

this is the correct package of your controller. If your controller is not instantiated by spring than double check also the spring config paths etc.

Comment: You are the CHAMP! Thanks a lot :) :) The problem was in Spring config paths. One last question please, can you provide me with code sample on where to place code to test Controller class initialization? so that if it happened next time due to controller initialization problem?

Comment: @Controller
public class HomeController {

public HomeController(){
 System.out.println("!!!!")
}
}

Just create a default constructor with some output and lets see whether the spring instantiates your bean or not. You could start the server in debug mode and just add there a debug point or whatever. The key is to see whether the default constructor is called or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the .htm from the URL. That is: http://[server][:port]/TestAOP/page1.

That should match the mapping on your controller.